# Sorting nested Array inside Array using sort

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sort nested array (array inside an array) i.e My array looks like this

```
const input = [[3,9],[7,12],[3,8],[6,8],[9,10],[2,9],[0,9],[3,9],[0,6],[2,8]]
```

To do that I wrote this logic

```js
const input = [[3,9],[7,12],[3,8],[6,8],[9,10],[2,9],[0,9],[3,9],[0,6],[2,8]]
    
    
     function sort (a,b) {
      if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1
      if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1
      if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        if (a.length > 1 && b.length > 1) {
          return sort(a.slice(0, 1), b.slice(0,1))
        }
        else return 0
      } 
    }

  console.log(input.sort((a,b) => {
    return sort(a,b)
  }))
```

but this is giving first element as `[0,9]` instead of `[0, 6]` and `[2, 9]` instead of `[2,8]` so on.

What I want is

- Compare first element, if first element is equal, compare second ending elemennt

So `[0, 6]` should be before `[0,9]`...

Comment: to fix the code you wrote, you'd need `return sort(a.slice(1, 2), b.slice(1,2))`

Answer (score 4):

All you need for the callback is `a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]`:

```js
const input = [[3,9],[7,12],[3,8],[6,8],[9,10],[2,9],[0,9],[3,9],[0,6],[2,8]]
console.log(input.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]))
```

If the array is of arbitrary length, then you do need a separate named function:

```js
const sort = (a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || sort(a.slice(1), b.slice(1));

const input = [[3,9],[7,12],[3,8],[6,8],[9,10],[2,9],[0,9],[3,9],[0,6],[2,8]]
console.log(input.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]))
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line of code `a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]`  in `input.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1])`

Comment: It will return the difference if the first items in the arrays are different. Otherwise, if they're the same, it'll return the difference between the second items in the arrays.